# get attached files in mail using Imapx in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, email-attachments, imapx

I am using `Imapx 2.0.0.9` to read the mails from gmail. It is working fine upto reading mails and get some files attached like `.docx`, `.xls` etc. But I am not getting the files attached with 
extensions like .txt, .rtf in attachment. Here is my code:

```
    var messages = client.Folders["INBOX"].Search("UNSEEN", true);
       foreach (var msg in messages)
       {

           msg.Process();
           msg.AddFlag(ImapX.ImapFlags.SEEN);
           if (msg.Attachments.Count > 0)
           {
                 for (int i = 0; i < msg.Attachments.Count; i++)
                 {
                      msg.Attachments[i].SaveFile("path to save file");
                 }
           }
       }
```

I am getting `msg.Attachments.Count = 0` when I attach file with `.txt`, `.rtf` extensions.
please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the developer of ImapX, yesterday there was a new release and the issue you mentioned here is fixed now. Please update to the latest version of the library.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, for your kind support.